# Wiring question wifi thermostats (Home wired with 2 wire)

Tags: thermostat, installation, wifi

I have a home that has 6 thermostats all wired with 2 wire. The homes heat is operated by a boiler connected to Honeywell zone valves. I am trying to install wifi thermostats and was wondering if it is possible. I was looking into the faststat howevver I didnt know if I would have to get one faststat for each thermostat or if I can by the model that allows you to connect 3 c wires and by two of them?

If someone could give me some direction I would greatly appriciate it!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Two-wire thermostats are usually associated with older homes.  Six zones are usually associated with newer homes.  Are you sure *all* your thermostats are cabled with no spare wires?

Comment: Can you post a wiring diagram of your system please? Also, I take it replacing the thermostat cables is off the table?

Answer (score 1):

I went through this same exercise recently.

AFAICT There is exactly one wifi thermostat on the market right now which works with 2-wire systems, and it isn't great.
The Lux GEO.
Don't consider this a product endorsement. The thermostat generally works but not perfectly.

They shipped the most recent batch with a defect on board. You need to connect it to an open 2.4ghz wifi network (no password) so that it can get the latest firmware before it will work with WPA2.

Are you certain you have only two conductors to each thermostat?

If so, and they connect directly to the zone valve, then you do have a c-wire (because the zone valve requires one) so it's possible you have other options.

Do you have one circulating pump for the whole system, with zones behind zone valves? Do you have relays from each zone valve to power on the pump?

If you use something like faststat you will need one for each thermostat, and assuming that multiple units don't interfere with each other.

Answer (score 1):

If all your thermostats are really wired with two-wire cables that have no spare wires in them, your options are:

- Where possible, run new cables to the thermostats.  For example if your system is in an unfinished basement (or attic) it should be relatively easy to run new cables to the floor immediately above (or below) it.  It's also possible (though unlikely) that the installer of a six-zone system was kind enough to leave nylon pulling string alongside the cables in some key places.
- There are "C wire adapters" available where you install a pair of widgets, one at each end of the cable, that provide all the necessary signals at both ends over a two-wire cable.
- You can install power supplies near each thermostat so they get power from a nearby outlet and only need two wires to the system.